# How to replace excessive SQL wildcard by single regex pattern?

Tags: java, regex

I am creating a function that strips the illegal wildcard patterns from the input string. The ideal solution should use a single regex expression, if at all possible.

The illegal wildcard patterns are: `%%` and `%_%`. Each instance of those should be replaced with `%`.

Here's the rub... I'm trying to perform some fuzz testing by running the function against various inputs to try to make it and break it.

It works for the most part; however, with complicated inputs, it doesn't.

#### The rest of this question has been updated:

<strike>The following inputs should return empty string (not an exhaustive list):</strike>

The following inputs should return `%` (not an exhaustive list).

- %_%
- %%
- %%_%%
- %_%%%
- %%_%_%
- %%_%%%_%%%_%

There will be cases where there are other characters with the input... like:

- Foo123%_%

  - Should return "Foo123%"
- B4r$%_%

  - Should return "B4r$%"
- B4rs%%_%

  - Should return "B4rs%"
- %%Lorem_%%

  - Should return "%Lorem_%"

I have tried using several different patterns and my tests are failing.

```
String input = "%_%%%%_%%%_%";

// old method:
public static String ancientMethod1(String input){
    if (input == null)
        return "";
    return input.replaceAll("%_%", "").replaceAll("%%", "");  // Output: ""
}

// Attempt 1:
// Doesn't quite work right.
// "A%%" is returned as "A%%" instead of "A%"
public static String newMethod1(String input) {
    String result = input;
    while (result.contains("%%") || result.contains("%_%"))
        result = result.replaceAll("%%","%").replaceAll("%_%","%");
    if (result.equals("%"))
        return "";
    return input;
}

// Attempt 2:
// Succeeds, but I would like to simplify this:
public static String newMethod2(String input) {
    if (input == null)
        return "";

    String illegalPattern1 = "%%";
    String illegalPattern2 = "%_%";
    String result = input;

    while (result.contains(illegalPattern1) || result.contains(illegalPattern2)) {
        result = result.replace(illegalPattern1, "%");
        result = result.replace(illegalPattern2, "%");
    }

    if (result.equals("%") || result.equals("_"))
        return "";

    return result;
}
```

Here's a more complete defined example of how I'm using this: https://gist.github.com/sometowngeek/697c839a1bf1c9ee58be283b1396cf2e

Comment: It's worthwhile to figure out a way to describe the strings you want to match in words.  For example, how about this: "a sequence of '%' and '\_' characters, beginning and ending with '%', and not containing two consecutive '\_' characters.

Comment: If I understand this now right, `%%_%%%_%%%_%` should result in `%`, right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Correct.

Comment: Then `.replaceAll("%[%_]*%", "%")` should work, see https://regex101.com/r/2d0Agd/1. I updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56456211/3832970), but the regex is still the same.

Comment: You say `%?(?:_?%)+` works for you, but [it turns](https://regex101.com/r/GXQ5jv/1) `%%Lorem_%%` into `%Lorem%`, while you say you expect `%Lorem_%`. Please just say what the *rules* are, your examples are baffling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regular expression string matches all your examples:

```
"%(?:_?%)+"
```

It matches strings consisting of a '%' character followed by one or more sequences consisting of zero or one '_' character and one '%' character (close to literal translation), which is another way of saying what I did in comments: "a sequence of '%' and '_' characters, beginning and ending with '%', and not containing two consecutive '_' characters".

Comment: I work long hours and I have limited access to StackOverflow, so I'm checking this at home... I'm out of time tonight, so I'll try your suggestion tomorrow after work.

Comment: Your answer is ***very*** close... `%?(?:_?%)+` seems to work so far. I'll do more testing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, if the listed inputs might have other instances, if not, maybe an expression with start and end anchor would be much applicable here, either one by one, or with something similar to:

```
^%{1,3}(_%{1,3})?(_%{1,3})?(_%)?$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GmPNE8/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "^%{1,3}(_%{1,3})?(_%{1,3})?(_%)?$";
final String string = "%_%\n"
     + "%%\n"
     + "%%_%%\n"
     + "%%%_%%%\n"
     + "%_%%%\n"
     + "%%%_%\n"
     + "%%_%_%\n"
     + "%%_%%%_%%%_%";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Ooh, that jex regulex thing is fun!  I hadn't seen it before.

Comment: I agree with @JohnBollinger, jex regulex is very nice!

Comment: This is a really good suggestion; however, it only limits itself to up to 3 instances. I feel, given the mind of an attacker, I should be encompassing an infinite number of occurrences. And no... the input doesn't always start with `%` or `_`. It could be alphanumeric with some special characters (except `%` and `_`).

Comment: I just went into the requirements for the search function a little deeper... It seems I'm actually supposed to replace the invalids (`%%` and `%_%`) with `%`, then if the result is just `%`, an *empty string* is to be returned. I'll update the question...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all the patterns start with `%`, then have 0+ `%` or `_` chars and end with `%`.

Use a mere

```
input = input.replaceAll("%[%_]*%", "%");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2d0Agd/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%25%5B%25_%5D*%25):

[image]

**Details**

- `%` - a `%` char
- `[%_]*` - 0 or more `%` or `_` chars
- `%` - a `%` char.

Comment: Er... The patterns actually don't always start with either a `%` or `_`. It may include any alphanumeric or special characters. I'll update my question.

Comment: @Sometowngeek *Any alphanumeric or special characters* - so, any char :) ? What are you doing?

Comment: @Sometowngeek Those are examples. What are the *requirements*, rules? [My regex](https://regex101.com/r/QmyaMI/1) still works, only `B4rs%%_%` is turned to `B4rs`, not `B4rs%%_%`. Why should it be `B4rs%`?

Comment: @Sometowngeek Try `while (s.contains("%_%") || s.contains("%%")) { s = s.replace("%_%", "").replace("%%", ""); }`.

Comment: `%` and `_` are valid wildcards, as long as there is another alphanumeric or special characters (except `%` and `_`). In the case of **B4rs%%_%**, it should be stripped down to **B4rs%**.

Answer (score 0):

Your `newMethod1` actually works, except you have a typo - you're returning the input parmeter, not the result of your processing!

Change:

```
return input; // oops!
```

to:

```
return result;
```

Also, because you're not using regex, you should use [`replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) rather than [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)), ie:

```
result = result.replace("%%","%").replace("%_%","%"); // still replaces all occurrences
```

`replace()` still replaces all occurrences.

---

BTW, although not as strict, this works for all of your (currently) posted examples:

```
public static String myMethod(String input) {
    return input.replaceAll("%[%_]*", "%");
}
```

Comment: Hrmm... I feel I should use `replaceAll()` because the pattern occur more than once, and I am trying to make sure there is only a single instance of a wildcard pattern (either `%` ***OR*** `_` by itself, or surrounded by other characters). Does that make sense?

Comment: @Sometowngeek as I said, `replace()` replaces **all** matches. The only difference between `replace()` and `replaceAll()` is that `replaceAll()` uses *regex* to match, where `replace()` just matches *plain text*. Please follow the links in my answer to the documentation for each method for a complete description.

Comment: Apologies - I forgot to correctly edit my answer to replace `replaceAll` with `replace` - fixed now.

Comment: Sorry... for some reason I didn't recognize them as links. Thanks for the clarification :)